# double looping in two different columns+subroutine calling

Tags: loops, excel, for-loop, goto, vba

**Background:**

The first sub checks the format of each cell in "column A" in worksheet "sheet1", by going through each cell the same column in sheet (template), if no similar is found Subroutine FlagError is called to store the mistake in sheetname&now (the now part allows me to create a new error sheet every second without getting duplicates) work sheet.

**Issues:**

- An error saying that sheet out of range and highlighting the line
  sheets("template").activate :**SOLVED**: WAS MISSING "".Thanks simoco for pointing that out.
- I want to get rid of all goto statements, but my limited technical knowledge is well.. limiting me, can some one please help me modifying the code.

**The stuff:**

```
Global sheetname As String

Sub errorsinsight_plus()
     sheetname = "errorsheet" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd ss_nn_hh")
    Dim i As Long, r As Range, j As Long
    Dim ucolumn As String
    Dim counter As Integer: counter = 1

Sheets.Add.Name = sheetname

    Sheets("sheet1").Activate

 ' if your data is in a different column then change A to some other letter(s)
    ucolumn = "A" 'sample number

  'finds error in sample code


For i = 2 To Range(ucolumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = Range(ucolumn & i)
Dim samplenof As Range
Sheets("template").Activate
For j = 1 To Range(ucolumn & Rows.Count)
Set samplenof = Range(ucolumn & j)
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   If Len(r) = 14 Then
     Dim xcheck1 As Boolean
     xcheck1 = r Like samplenof
        If xcheck1 = True Then
        GoTo nexti1
        Else
         GoTo nextj1
        End If
   ElseIf Len(r) = 15 Then
     Dim xcheck2 As Boolean
     xcheck2 = r Like samplenof
        If xcheck2 = True Then
        GoTo nexti1
        Else
       GoTo nextj1
        End If
  FlagErrors ucolumn, i, r, counter
  Else: FlagErrors ucolumn, i, r, counter
  End If
nextj1:
   Next j
nexti1:
Next i

end sub

Public Sub FlagErrors(ucolumn As String, i As Long, r As Range, ByRef counter As Integer)
    Sheets(sheetname).Activate
    Dim xerror As Range, yerror As Range
    Range("A" & counter) = ucolumn & i
    Range("B" & counter) = r
    Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    counter = counter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: If `template` is a sheet name (not a VBA variable) you need to use `Sheets("template").Activate` instead `Sheets(template).Activate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of this answer sought clarification which was given in the first two comments.

**Change 1**

I have added `Option Explicit` at the top.  This causes the compiler to insist that all variables are declared.  Without it statements such as `Count = Conut + 1` implicitly declares `Conut`.  Such errors can be a nightmare to locate.

**Change 2**

When you come back to this routine in 12 months, will you immediately know what `i`, `j` and `counter` are?  You need a system for naming variables so you (or colleagues) can easily tell their purpose after you have forgotten.  You may not like my naming system.  Fine, pick one you do like.

```
Your name   My name
    i       RowSheet1Crnt
    j       RowTemplateCrnt
 counter    RowErrorCrnt
```

**Change 3**

You have:

```
Set r = Range(ucolumn & i)
If Len(r) = 14 Then
```

`r` is a range.  The default property of a range is `Value`.  So `Len(r)` is the equivalent of `Len(r.Value)`.  But when I see `Len(r)` I have to know `r` is a one cell range to decypher this statement.  I avoid assuming the default property of any object.  For ranges, I always include `.Value` because I believe it makes the code more readable.

However, you only use `r` to get the value.  I have dropped `r` and replaced it with a string variable.  I do not know what `Range(ucolumn & i)` is so I cannot give it a meaningful name.  I have chosen `CellValueSheet1Test` but you should replace this name.

So I would have the following but for other changes:

```
CellValueSheet1Test = Range(ucolumn & RowSheet1Crnt).Value
If Len(CellValueSheet1Test) = 14 Then
```

**Change 4**

You use `Range(ucolumn & RowSheet1Crnt).Value`.  I have used `Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, ucolumn)`.  There is nothing wrong with `Range` but I find `Cells` more flexible.  The second parameter can be a column identifier such as "A" or a column number such as 1.  This is very convenient when you are operating across a number of columns.

**Change 5**

You switch worksheets using Activate.  Even if you include `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, there is a certain amount of screen repainting everytime you switch.  It is a statement to avoid if possible.  Consider:

```
CellValueSheet1Test = Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, ucolumn).Value

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
  CellValueSheet1Test = .Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, ucolumn).Value
End With
```

The first statement operates on the active worksheet.  In the second group, the dot before `Cells` means this operates on the worksheet specificed in the `With` statement.  I do not have to switch to a worksheet to access its contents.

`With`s can be nested:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
  With .Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, ucolumn)
    .Value = "X"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
  End With
End With
```

**Change 6**

If I was doing a lot with a particular worksheet, I would use the `With Worksheets` statement.  You are only accessing one cell at a time and it is faster accessing worksheets via references.

I have:

```
Dim WshtSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim WshtTemplate As Worksheet

Set WshtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WshtTemplate = Worksheets("template")

CellValueSheet1Test = WshtSheet1.Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, ucolumn).Value
```

I think this is definitely the best way to access worksheet "Sheet1".  I have used the same technique for worksheet "template" but some might argue that `With` would have been better.  A difficulty with Excel VBA is that there is usually several ways of achieving the same effect and it is not always obvious which is the best to use.  I find each programmer has their own favourites - you are seeing mine.  The trouble is that as you look at the work of different programmers, each will have their own favourites.  You have to be aware of every technique, even if you do not like them, because others use them.

**Change 7**

You have:

```
If Len(r) = 14 Then
  Dim xcheck1 As Boolean
  xcheck1 = r Like samplenof
    If xcheck1 = True Then
    GoTo nexti1
    Else
     GoTo nextj1
    End If
ElseIf Len(r) = 15 Then
  Dim xcheck2 As Boolean
  xcheck2 = r Like samplenof
    If xcheck2 = True Then
      GoTo nexti1
    Else
     GoTo nextj1
    End If
```

I cannot see any difference between the code for length 14 and 15 so I have combined then.  I see no advantage in using `xcheck1` and `xcheck2` so, but for other changes, this would have become:

```
If Len(r) = 14 Or Len(r) = 15 Then
    If r Like samplenof Then
    GoTo nexti1
    Else
     GoTo nextj1
    End If
```

**Change 8**

The block of code with the `GoTo`s caused me the most difficulty trying to understand what you are trying to achieve.

It appears to me that if the length of the value from worksheet "Sheet1" is not 14 or 15, it is an error; there is no need to check worksheet "template".  So that test can be taken outside the inner loop.  I think you want an error reported if the value from worksheet "Sheet1" is not `Like` any value from worksheet "template".  You have a call of `FlagErrors` just above the `Else` but I cannot see that it can be executed.  I have completed recoded this block but I cannot be sure I have achieved the effect you want.

**Non change**

You use:

```
FlagErrors ucolumn, RowSheet1Crnt, CellValueSheet1Test, RowErrorCrnt
```

I prefer:

```
Call FlagErrors(ucolumn, RowSheet1Crnt, CellValueSheet1Test, RowErrorCrnt)
```

My preference is probably more to do with the other programming languages I know.  I do not know any other language that allows the format you are using.  However, I do not know of a disadvantage with your format so I have left it.

**Revised code**

I have no means of testing this code.  I have explained every change so, if it does not work as you wish, you should be able to identify the reason.  Good luck.

```
Option Explicit
Global sheetname As String

Sub errorsinsight_plus()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sheetname = "errorsheet" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd ss_nn_hh")

    Dim ucolumn As String

    Dim CellValueSheet1Test As String
    Dim CellValueTemplateTest As String
    Dim MatchFound As Boolean
    Dim RowErrorCrnt As Long
    Dim RowSheet1Crnt As Long
    Dim RowSheet1Last As Long
    Dim RowTemplateCrnt As Long
    Dim RowTemplateLast As Long
    Dim WshtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim WshtTemplate As Worksheet

    Set WshtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set WshtTemplate = Worksheets("template")

    Sheets.Add.Name = sheetname

    ' if your data is in a different column then change A to some other letter(s)
    ucolumn = "A" 'sample number

    RowSheet1Last = WshtSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, ucolumn).End(xlUp).Row
    RowTemplateLast = WshtTemplate.Cells(Rows.Count, ucolumn).End(xlUp).Row
    RowErrorCrnt = 1

    'finds error in sample code
    For RowSheet1Crnt = 2 To RowSheet1Last
      CellValueSheet1Test = WshtSheet1.Cells(RowSheet1Crnt, ucolumn).Value
      If Len(CellValueSheet1Test) = 14 Or _
         Len(CellValueSheet1Test) = 15 Then
        MatchFound = False
        For RowTemplateCrnt = 2 To RowTemplateLast
          CellValueTemplateTest = WshtTemplate.Cells(RowTemplateCrnt, ucolumn).Value
          If CellValueSheet1Test Like CellValueTemplateTest Then
            MatchFound = True
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      Else
        ' Length of test value is neither 14 or 15.
         FlagErrors ucolumn, RowSheet1Crnt, CellValueSheet1Test, RowErrorCrnt
      End If
      If Not MatchFound Then
        FlagErrors ucolumn, RowSheet1Crnt, CellValueSheet1Test, RowErrorCrnt
      End If
    Next RowSheet1Crnt

End Sub
Public Sub FlagErrors(ByVal ucolumn As String, ByVal RowSheet1 As Long, _
                      ByVal CellValueSheet1 As String, ByRef RowError As Long)

  With Sheets(sheetname)
    .Cells(RowError, "A").Value = ucolumn & RowSheet1
    .Cells(RowError, "B").Value = CellValueSheet1
    RowError = RowError + 1
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Tony these sure were supposed to be the way you suggested.

Comment: ucolumnf is supposed to be replaced by samplenof

Comment: i guess nobody gets my messy code i'll just mark it as solved, thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried my alternative?  Although I cannot guarantee it without test data, I believe it does the same as the original.

Comment: I cant thank you enough, not only it works perfectly 100 times faster, but you also went through the trouble of explaining.

Comment: and about change 8 you guessed precisely what i failed to mention in the question, r cells must have a length of 14 or 15 before comparing it's format samplenof. otherwise it's flagged as an error.

Comment: revising the code i see now that the if len(CellValueSheet1Test) statement isnt needed anymore, since each format will have a length of 14 or 15 and if the CellVlaueSheet1Test has a different length an error will arise anyway.